# How to use except but excluding a column from the except operator comparison -psql?

Tags: postgresql, except

I want to compare two sets of columns but exclude one column from the comparison as it will never be in the second table and I need it on my result.
So, explaining:

columns for both tables:

- `ID` (unique value, so I do not want to compare)
- `amount`
- `email`
- `date`

What I want to achieve:
Get all transactions from table 1 that has the exact same values on `amount`, `email` and `date`. I also want the `ID` to be in the final result set, but if I compare using the `except` clause, I will have 0 results at my query.

code:

```
Select /*ignoreAtComparison*/ t1.ID, t1.amount, t1.email, t1.date from t1

except

Select /*ignoreAtComparison*/ t2.ID, t2.amount, t2.email, t2.date from t2 ;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit and then take the tour and also see the "help us to help you" blog. The tour and blog are at the bottom left of the page.

Comment: Any reasons why inner join can not be used?

Comment: The wording here is not very clear: _'Get all transactions from table 1 that has the exact same values on amount, email and date'_ - same as what?  It would help if you presented some example data sets and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 5):

`except` can be re-written as `not exists` query:

```
select t1.id, t1.amount, t1.email, t1.date
from t1
where not exists (select 1 
                  from t2
                  where t2.amount = t1.amount
                    and t2.email = t1.email
                    and t2.date = t1.date);
```

But your statement seems to indicate you do not actually want `except` but something entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

This query should get only lines from `t1` where amount, email and date match exactly with one line of t2.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.amount, t1.email, t1.date
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.email = t2.email AND t1.date = t2.date;
```

Comment: That would be `intersect` not `except` but I agree the question is very unclear.